# Check if lists are disjoint

Tags: c#, disjoint-sets

I need to check if two lists have any elements in common. *I just need a yes/no* - I don't need the actual list of common elements.

I could use `Enumerable.Intersect()` but this does actually return the set of matching items which seems like it would require extra overhead. **Is there a better method for checking if lists are disjoint?**

---

My lists do actually happen to be `List<T>` but that isn't crucial and I could use something like `HashSet` (say) if that were more convenient. i.e., I don't want to unnecessarily constrain potential solutions.

Grazie mille

Comment: stick .Any() after the Intersect.

Comment: `Enumerable.Intersect().Any()` should (IIRC, anyway) return as soon as the first intersect occurance is found, rather than returning the whole set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simplest version (using Intersect):

```
 public bool Compare(List<T> firstCollection, List<T> secondCollection)
 {
    return firstCollection.Intersect(secondCollection).Any();
 }
```

Only caveat is either `T` shall implement `IEquatable<T>` or pass custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` in the `Intersect` call. Also make sure that `GetHashCode` is overriden along with `Equals`

**Edit 1:**

This version using Dictionary will not just provide `boolean` comparison, but also the elements. In this solution `Dictionary` in the end would contain data related to number of intersecting elements, number of elements in one of the collection but not in another, so fairly durable. This solution also has `IEquatable<T>` requirement

```
public bool CompareUsingDictionary(IEnumerable<T> firstCollection, IEnumerable<T> secondCollection)
    {
        // Implementation needs overiding GetHashCode methods of the object base class in the compared type
        // Obviate initial test cases, if either collection equals null and other doesn't then return false. If both are null then return true.
        if (firstCollection == null && secondCollection != null)
            return false;
        if (firstCollection != null && secondCollection == null)
            return false;
        if (firstCollection == null && secondCollection == null)
            return true;

        // Create a dictionary with key as Hashcode and value as number of occurences
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        // If the value exists in first list , increase its count
        foreach (T item in firstCollection)
        {
            // Get Hash for each item in the list
            int hash = item.GetHashCode();

            // If dictionary contains key then increment 
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(hash))
            {
                dictionary[hash]++;
            }
            else
            {
                // Initialize he dictionary with value 1
                dictionary.Add(hash, 1);
            }
        }

        // If the value exists in second list , decrease its count
        foreach (T item in secondCollection)
        {
            // Get Hash for each item in the list
            int hash = item.GetHashCode();

            // If dictionary contains key then decrement
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(hash))
            {
                dictionary[hash]--;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Check whether any value is 0
        return dictionary.Values.Any(numOfValues => numOfValues == 0);
    }
```